# Switching to a UITabBarController at a specific index

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to switch back to a UITabBarController at a specific index. My method does not appear to be working. Here is my code:

BaseViewController.m

```
-(void)switchTabView: (NSString*) viewName inx: (int) index
{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *view = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewName];
    view.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
    [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ChildViewController.m (inherits BaseViewController)

```
- (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self switchTabView:@"tabView" inx:1];
}
```

It goes back to the UITabBarController, but the index argument does not seem to matter since it always goes to index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
-(void)switchTabView: (NSString*) viewName inx: (int) index
{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *view = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewName];
    view.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
    [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

to

```
-(void)switchTabView: (NSString*) viewName inx: (int) index
{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *view = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewName];
    view.selectedIndex = index;
    [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. Just needed to change view.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index; to view.selectedIndex = index;. Thanks!

Comment: Can't for another 30 seconds :P